# A python proxy in less than 100 lines of code

Tags: python, proxy, smtp

Today I found some interesting code which says it can implement a tcp proxy within 100 lines of code.

The code is on gist: [A python proxy in less than 100 lines of code](https://gist.github.com/gschizas/3731989).

I tried it, and it works - and I have changed it for my own use...

However, what's out of my knowledge is why it always makes `forward_to = ('smtp.zaz.ufsk.br', 25)` as the destination address? And someone says it can be changed to `('localhost', 25)`. Can it? And what is the principle used here?

Comment: `('localhost', 25)`, should work, why not, try and see if it works. It should as long as you port forward.

Comment: @downshift  and why connect to port 25 can make a effect as port forward? any documents say it? thks

Comment: yes sure, forward_to uses [socket](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) interface to connect to a port that user can access an open by port forward through your router, which is part of networking and not python specific.